# How to group by in pandas keeping a specific order?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the pandas package of python I'd like to group by, so that I keep a specific order. The below code seems to do this, but is there a faster / simpler way? Or is it guaranteed, that the group by function of pandas keeps the order of records in the source dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd

sep = ' - '
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,"apple",1],[1,"banana",3],[1,"pear",2],[2,"lemon",3],[2,"orange",1],[2,"apple",2]])
df1.columns = ["id","product","seq"]
df1 = df1.sort_values(by=["id","seq"])
pd.DataFrame(df1.groupby('id',as_index=False)['product'].apply(lambda x: sep.join(x)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use parameter `sort=False`, also `DataFrame` contructor is not necessary:

```
df2 = df1.groupby('id', sort=False)['product'].apply(sep.join).reset_index()
print (df2)
   id                 product
0   1   apple - pear - banana
1   2  orange - apple - lemon
```